# http status 404 in struts 2 result

Tags: struts2

im in learning struts 2.
i create a simple project that can add and list the PRODUCT that user add. list is my first page and show all product that added. it is my struts.xml file:

```
<struts>

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <default-action-ref name="listProduct" />

    <action name="listProduct" class="control.ProductHandler" method="list">
        <result name="success">/list.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="addProduct" class="control.ProductHandler" method="add">
        <result name="success">/listProduct</result>
    </action>

    <action name="*Form">
        <result>{1}.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

</struts>
```

when i enter `localhost:8080/product` in then browser it show me list.jsp file. in this file i have a link that with it i can goto add.jsp file. href of this link is `addForm`.
in add.jsp file i have 3 text field and a submit button. when entered data added action class return "success" and i most goto `localhost:8080/product` (default page) but it show me :

> HTTP Status 404 - /product/listProduct

this is my action file:

```
public String list(){
    products=Database.get();
    return "success";
}

public String add(){
    if (add!=null){
        Product product=new Product(name, producer, price);
        Database.add(product);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

where is my mistake?
thanks.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to your `listProduct` action?

Comment: yes. i will redirect to listProduct when product added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to redirect to another action use [`redirectAction`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html) result type.

```
<action name="addProduct" class="control.ProductHandler" method="add">
  <result name="success" type="redirectAction">listProduct</result>
</action>
```